# Imprecise floats in Tupper's self-referential formula

Tags: python-3.x, bigfloat

I am trying to make a Python program that plots [Tupper's self-referential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula) and I have run into some problems.

First my program couldn’t handle the big floats it had to handle so I decided to use `BigFloats` to sort out my problems. It worked, sort of. My problem is that I have a 540 digits long number that needs to be multiplied with a `BigFloat` and when I do that it rounds the number making it inexact which cause problems later. I have tried to raise the `precision` to 1000 and it still keeps rounding the variable.

The thing is that some of the numbers can be processed without `BigFloat` to the exact value but some numbers can neither be processed normally nor with `BigFloat` right now.

Here is one of the calculations that goes wrong (this one is able to be processed without `BigFloat`):

```
import bigfloat
y = 960939379918958884971672962127852754715004339660129306651505519271702802395266424689642842174350718121267153782770623355993237280874144307891325963941337723487857735749823926629715517173716995165232890538221612403238855866184013235585136048828693337902491454229288667081096184496091705183454067827731551705405381627380967602565625016981482083418783163849115590225610003652351370343874461848378737238198224849863465033159410054974700593138339226497249461751545728366702369745461014655997933798537483143786841806593422227898388722980000748404719
x = 0
with bigfloat.precision(1000):
    (y//17 * bigfloat.pow(2,0)) % 2
```

That code should return 1 but instead it returns 0.

Is there a way to make `BigFloat` more accurate so I can use it in my program?

Comment: To the `bigfloat` problem:  (1) don't use bigfloat; use gmpy2 instead, and (2) the precision in bigfloat is the number of *bits*, not the number of decimal digits.  For 540 digits, you'd need about 1800 bits of precision.  If you try with a precision of 2000, you'll see the `1` that you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any floating point math for Tupper's formula. The trick is that 2<sup>-x</sup> is the same as 1/2<sup>x</sup> so you only have to work with integers because you do not need to calculate the floating point number 2<sup>-x</sup> and multiply it with an integer but instead calculate the integer 2<sup>x</sup> and divide an other integer by this integer. Applied on Tupper's formula the 2<sup>-17*int(x) - int(y)%17</sup> part becomes 1/2<sup>17*int(x) + int(y)%17</sup>.

See the following version of Tupper's function that completely operates in integer domain (in case you do not know what `**` is, it is [Python's power operator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#pow)):

```
def tuppers_formula(x, y):
    """Return True if point (x, y) (x and y both start at 0) is to be drawn black, False otherwise
    """
    k = 960939379918958884971672962127852754715004339660129306651505519271702802395266424689642842174350718121267153782770623355993237280874144307891325963941337723487857735749823926629715517173716995165232890538221612403238855866184013235585136048828693337902491454229288667081096184496091705183454067827731551705405381627380967602565625016981482083418783163849115590225610003652351370343874461848378737238198224849863465033159410054974700593138339226497249461751545728366702369745461014655997933798537483143786841806593422227898388722980000748404719
    return ((k + y)//17//2**(17*int(x) + int(y)%17))%2 > 0.5
```

You can test this function with the following code that "draws" the result of Tupper's formula into a text file.

```
import codecs
import os
with codecs.open("tupper.txt", "w", "utf-8") as f:
    values = [[tuppers_formula(x, y) for x in range(106)] for y in range(17)]
    for row in values:
        for value in row[::-1]: # x = 0 starts at the left so reverse the whole row
            if value:
                f.write("\u2588") # Write a block
            else:
                f.write(" ")
        f.write(os.linesep)
```

The result is the file `tupper.txt` with the content:

```
        █                   █                █ ██ █     █                █  █ █     █    █ ██ █      █   █
        █                   █ █      █       █  █ █     █                █  █ █     █    █  █ █      █   █
██      █                  █  █      █    ██ █  █ █ █ █ █ ██ ████  ███ ███ █  █ █ █ █    █  █  █      █  █
 █      █                  █  █  █ █ █       █ █  █  █  █    █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █  █ █ █ █    █ █   █      █  █
 █      █                  █  █  █ █ █       █ █  █ █ █ █    █ █ █ ███ ███ █  █  █  █    █ █   █      █  █
 █      █               █ █   █   █  █  ██        █     █                  █  █ █   █  █       █   ██  █ █
███   █ █               █ █   █  █   █ █  █       █     █                   █ █     █  █      █   █  █ █ █
     █  █ ██ █   ██   ███ █   █      █   █        ███ ███                   █ ███ ███ █       █     █  █ █
███ █   █ █ █ █ █  █ █  █ █   █ ████ █  █                                                          █   █ █
     █  █ █ █ █ █  █ █  █ █   █      █ █                                                          █    █ █
██    █ █ █ █ █  ██   ███ █   █ █ ██ █ ████                                                       ████ █ █
  █     █                 █   █ █  █ █                                                          █      █ █
 █      █                  █  █ █  █ █                                                          █     █  █
█       █                  █  █ █ █  █                                                         █      █  █
███     █                  █  █ █ █  █                                                                █  █
        █                   █ █      █                                                               █   █
        ███                 █ ███  ███                                                               █ ███
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got my code to work (I already had a way of plotting the function). But there is still one thing that I can't understand about the formula. If y and x are always integers, then why do you need to take the floor of both of them ("2^-17*floor(x)-mod(floor(y),17")?